# Transform OpenModelica code to a schematic model

Tags: modelica, dymola, openmodelica

I created my personal program of a system similar to a heat pump. Can I transform this code to a schematic model where I can see the changes happening within a system in a sort of animation
for example let's say a liquid variation level in a tank?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, In Modelica it is possible to:

- Create diagrams of your models; in Modelica Standard Library there are a number of such fluid examples in Modelica.Fluid.Examples - that's as close to a schematic diagram you will get
- Animate such diagrams; e.g., Modelica.Fluid.Examples.Tanks.ThreeTanks - this is done using DynamicSelect - as described in the specification https://specification.modelica.org/maint/3.5/annotations.html#variable-graphics-and-schematic-animation

The diagram annotations are standardized in Modelica, but exactly how to create the diagram and animate depends on your tool.

In Dymola you animate using the play-button in the simulation-tab. The diagram can be made graphically except for the DynamicSelect that you have added in the text-layer. I would assume it is similar in other tools.